# Sign out redirect path for devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have overriden Devise's sign out path and made it request.referer. The problem with that is if the user is on a page which has the authenticate_user! before filter applied, I am sent to the sign in page and shown an error. This is not ideal, and I would like to redirect to the root_path ONLY when the user is coming from a path which has authentication requirements. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up inspecting the callbacks for the controller that the referrer url is associated with. If there are any `authenticate_*!` callbacks, they are each inspected to see if there are any actions specified in the `@if` instance variable. If there are none, the callback is applied to all of the actions and we know that the referring url is from a restricted action. If there are actions specified, we use regex to check if the referring action is restricted or not.

Any of the callbacks which meet the criteria are added to an array. After looping through the callbacks, we check if that array is empty. If it is, we send the user back to `request.referer`. If it is not empty, that means that sending them to `request.referer` will redirect them to the sign in page and show an error. In that case, we send the user to `root_path`.

If anything raises an error, the user is sent to `root_path`.

Here is the code:

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  begin
    controller_name = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.referer)[:controller]
    controller_class = "#{controller_name}_controller".camelize.constantize
    authentication_callbacks = controller_class._process_action_callbacks.select { |callback| callback.filter.match /authenticate_\w+!/ }
    action_name = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.referer)[:action]

    restricting_callbacks = []

    authentication_callbacks.each do |callback|
      callback_scope = callback.instance_variable_get(:@if)
      if callback_scope.empty? || callback_scope.first.match(/action_name\s==\s(\'|\")#{Regexp.quote(action_name)}(\'|\")/)
        restricting_callbacks << callback
      end
    end

    restricting_callbacks.empty? ? request.referer : root_path
  rescue Exception => e
    request.referer
  end
end
```